# How to merge many chunks of mediaRecorder into one video in amazon-S3?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

My idea is use MediaRecorder to capture screen, and upload video to s3.
I want to upload video in real time, so every second I will use axios to upload chunk into s3. Here is my code:

```
mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function (e) {
  chunks.push(e.data);

  const chunk = new FormData();
  chunk.append("file", e.data);
  part++;
  axios.post(`http://mywebsite.com/uploadChunk?part=${part}`, chunk);
});
mediaRecorder.start(1000);
```

I send a post request to my server (nodejs), and use library multer-s3 to upload.

It works well, and my files in s3 will looks like this:

[image]

And my question is: When I stop recording, how I can merge all this files in same folder into one .webm file?